# BufferedWriter and printing name and duration entered by user on JTextArea

Tags: java, user-interface, bufferedwriter

This function says that if the button "generate report" is pressed a text file will be generated. It will have the title from label1, date&time, and Activity name & Activity duration which was entered by the user in jTextArea in the form "activityname,duration,parent + acitivityname,duration,parent'  here the delimiter is +

```
else if(str.equals("Generate Report"))
    {
            try {
                FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("D:\\Report.txt");
                BufferedWriter buffer = new BufferedWriter(fw);
                String title="Title: "+lb1.getText();
                DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/YYYY HH:mm:ss");
                Date date = new Date();
                buffer.write(title);
                buffer.newLine();
                buffer.write("\nDate and Time of Creation: "+dateFormat.format(date));

                buffer.newLine();
                //ENTER YOUR CODE HERE TO PRINT ALL ACTIVITY NAMES & DURATION 



                buffer.write("\nList of activities & their duration: " + ));

                buffer.close();
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
    }
```

**Node.java** 
    //this class sees the activity name and duration and parents for every node entered by user

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Node {

private String activityName;
private int duration;
private ArrayList<String> parents = new ArrayList<String>();
private boolean end;

public Node() {
    this.activityName = "ExampleActivity";
    this.duration = 1;
    this.parents.add("null");
    this.end = false;
}
public Node(String activityName, int duration, ArrayList<String> parents) {
    this.activityName = activityName;
    this.duration = duration;
    this.parents = (ArrayList<String>) parents.clone();
    this.end = false;
}
public String getActivityName() {
    return activityName;
}
public void setActivityName(String activityName) {
    this.activityName = activityName;
}
public int getDuration() {
    return duration;
}
public void setDuration(int duration) {
    this.duration = duration;
}
public ArrayList<String> getParents() {
    return parents;
}
public void setParents(ArrayList<String> parents) {
    for(int i=0;i<parents.size();i++) {
        this.parents.add(parents.get(i));
    }
}
public boolean getEnd() {
    return end;
}
public void setEnd( ArrayList<Node> nodes  ){
    for( Node node : nodes ) {
        if( node.parents.contains( this.activityName ) ) return;
    }
    this.end = true;
}
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Node [activityName=" + activityName + ", duration=" + duration
            + ", parents=" + parents + ", end=" + end + "]";
}
```

}

**NodeBuilder.java**
    //This class builds every node

```
  import java.util.ArrayList;
  import java.util.Scanner;

public class NodeBuilder {
    ArrayList<Node> nodes = new ArrayList<Node>();

ArrayList<String> parents = new ArrayList<String>();

public void add(String input) {

        //Receive user node input
        String activityName;
                    int duration;

        //Setting up new Scanner and delimiter
        Scanner s = new Scanner(input);
        s.useDelimiter(",");

        //Set node variables with user input
        if(s.hasNext()) {
            activityName = s.next();
            //System.out.println(activityName);
        } else
            activityName = "Activity " + "not entered";

        if(s.hasNext()) {
            duration = s.nextInt();
            //System.out.println(duration);
        } else
            duration = 0;


        while (s.hasNext()) {
            parents.add(s.next());
        }

        Node myNode = new Node(activityName, duration, parents);
        nodes.add(myNode);
        parents.clear();
        s.close();
static boolean hasKids(Node node, ArrayList<Node> nodes) {
    for(int i=0;i<nodes.size();i++) {
        if(nodes.get(i).getParents().contains(node.getActivityName())) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

}

Desired Output for Text file:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/gQBwR.png

Comment: An aside: no matter if you use the modern `DateTimeFormatter` or the obsolete `SimpleDateFormat`, uppercase `YYYY` is for week year and only useful with a week number. Instead use lowercase `yyyy` (or `uuuu` with `DateTimeFormatter`). Format pattern letters are case sensitive.

Comment: User interface and output processor should be separated. The input of the user should be placed in a model and the model should be handed over to the output processer. This would also make the question a bit shorter.

Comment: Could you tell me how to do that? How do I it it generate report that lists all the activities in alphabetical order along with their duration as shown in the screenshot